# How to Rotate (Render)Transform an Ellipse around a point outside the Ellipse itself?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a timer control with a "dot" indicator moving around on a circle ([Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4bwP.jpg)).

How do you determine what point to rotate the indicator around? (what's the formuala?)

By trial and error I found out that correct point seems to be (10, 202.5) but I can't see any "pattern" related to the size/position/strokethickness of the canvas and/or indicator.

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="TestApp.Clock"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Name="clock"
    Width="512"
    Height="512"
    Background="White">
    <Canvas Width="512" Height="512">
        <Ellipse
            Canvas.Left="56"
            Canvas.Top="56"
            Width="400"
            Height="400"
            Opacity=".15"
            Stroke="Aqua"
            StrokeThickness="10" />
        <Ellipse
            Name="DotIndicator"
            Canvas.Left="248"
            Canvas.Top="52"
            Width="16"
            Height="16"
            Stroke="Aqua"
            StrokeThickness="10">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, ElementName=clock}" CenterX="10" CenterY="202.5" />
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use two Path elements with EllipseGeometries with a common coordinate origin. The "indicator" EllipseGeometry has a `Center` offset equal to the radius of the outer EllipseGeometry, so that you only can simply rotate it around the coordinate origin.

```
<Canvas Width="512" Height="512">
    <Canvas Canvas.Left="256" Canvas.Top="256">
        <Path Opacity=".15" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="10">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="200" RadiusY="200"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Aqua">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Center="0,-200"/>
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Angle, ElementName=clock}"/>
            </Path.RenderTransform>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

As an alternative to the Path's `RenderTransform` you may also set the EllipseGeometry's `Transform` property:

```
<Canvas Width="512" Height="512">
    <Canvas Canvas.Left="256" Canvas.Top="256">
        <Path Opacity=".15" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="10">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="200" RadiusY="200"/>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Aqua">
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8" Center="0,-200">
                    <EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                        <RotateTransform
                            Angle="{Binding Angle, ElementName=clock}"/>
                    </EllipseGeometry.Transform>
                </EllipseGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```